# accessing attributes names of class model not values in spring mvc

Tags: spring, class-members

I am using Spring 2.5 framework and stuck in one point. 
For example, I have a class(model) called Person.

```
public class Person(){
private String name;
private String surname;

getter, setter.....
```

I need to access the attributes name of Person class in Controller. For example, I want to get the

```
name
```

not the value of name. That is, I don't want to take info John as the name, ı want to take name word. How can I access attributes names in controller,  not values
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you're looking for reflection, have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields().

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will check it and say the the result.

Comment: Ok this is what I need. but can I access all class members in one for loop. For example, there is a class public class GetFields {
    public Long id;
    protected String name;
    private Date birthDate;
    Double weight; I want to access all fields in one for loop and get one or two or three ones that I need. Not like this one below:  for (Field field : fields) {
            System.out.println("Field name = " + field.getName());
            System.out.println("Field type = " + field.getType().getName());
        }

Comment: What I am looking exactly is reflection. Thanks sp00m